# Spring Hibernate maven POM

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven-2

I used Hibernate a while back, but it's way rusty. I want to get up and running again with this, used with Spring and annotations. Using current versions of all the dependencies obviously.

I am going to do this by writing some JUnit tests and with some in-memory database.

So I need a Maven POM dependencies element that pulls down the **minimal** dependency set: Hibernate, Spring, Database and test frameworks etc.  I will want to use Maven to start and stop the database as part of the test phase, so I need an in-memory database that has a maven plugin with the appropriate goals.

Thanks...

Comment: I think you should give it a shot yourself and then come to SO if you have specific questions, as opposed to the 'give me a working pom' approach.

Comment: @CarlosZ: fair point, but I am not looking for a POM just the right set of dependencies. For example, which in-memory database? Which deps do I need to specify for the full annotations thing...

Comment: please check the following blog: http://krams915.blogspot.com/. You'll find Spring-Hibernate Maven POMs for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have at the moment, I shall update later if necessary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>estivate</groupId>
    <artifactId>estivate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${javac.version}</source>
                    <target>${javac.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <javac.version>1.6</javac.version>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>3.5.1-Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


</project>
```

Comment: In case it helps others, in order to avoid problems retrieving javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1... use the log4j version to 1.2.17

Answer (score 4):

Below is POM with Spring, JPA, Oracle database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.lala</groupId>
<artifactId>lala</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>lala</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hibernate.jpa.version>2.0-cr-1</hibernate.jpa.version>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jasperreport.version>3.5.3</jasperreport.version>
</properties>

<build>

</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>taglibs</groupId> <artifactId>standard</artifactId> <version>1.1.2</version> <type>jar</type> <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4jdbc3</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc3</artifactId>
        <version>1.2beta2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>${jasperreport.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Wow, everything but the kitchen sink :D

Comment: It would have been nice if some of the irrelevant dependencies had been trimmed (e.g., most folks don't need barcode4j, no matter how good it is within its domain of applicability).

Comment: Thanks, I liked having the whole chebang. Easier to trim what't not needed than to look for what is.

Answer (score 4):

By the way, I got into the same question and I found this [tutorial](http://www.madbit.org/blog/programming/457/persisting-object-with-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4/) (using hibernate 4 and spring 3.1) which uses a quite smaller pom file (using mysql)

Here is a copy of their pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.madbit.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AOP dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence Management -->
        <dependency> <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- MySQL database driver -->
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- Hibernate -->
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```